# How to access existing data in before insert trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE borrow_document1 (
  id_borrow INT,
  id_client INT,
  id_document INT,
  isReturned number(1),
  CONSTRAINT PK_document PRIMARY KEY ( id_borrow));
```

I want to prevent borrowing the same document if it is not returned (if `isReturned` is equal to 0).
I am trying to create a `trigger` to do this job, but I don't know how to access to existing values in the table. here is what I have done:

```
create or replace trigger check_borrow
BEFORE INSERT on borrow_document1
for each row when(new.id_document = id_document)
BEGIN
IF ISRETURNED = 0 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20111,'document is borrowed');
end if;
END;
```

I know that this is wrong but I am just trying to show you what I need to do. The problem is that compiling this trigger returns error as `id_document` and `isreturned` are undeclared.
I might also have many documents that have the same id in my table but at most one of them is borrowed, because I need to keep the trace of the borrowed documents.
any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I tried this and it seems to work well :

```
create or replace trigger check_borrow
BEFORE INSERT on borrow_document1
for each row
declare
cpt int;
BEGIN
select COUNT(*) into cpt FROM borrow_document1 WHERE id_document = :new.id_document AND isReturned = '0';
IF cpt>0 THEN
        raise_application_error(-20111,'document is borrowed');
end if;
END;
/
```